# Почему memcpy "переворачивает" байты? С++

Tags: c++, память

Предположим есть набор сырых, никак не интерпретируемых байт, которые хранятся в массиве `raw_bytes`

```
// Последовательность из двух байтов. 0 и 
unsigned char raw_bytes[] {0, 1};
```

Такая последовательность байт в памяти должна выглядеть как `0000.0000 0000.0001`. При попытке скопировать два байта в одну переменную типа `unsigned short int` столкнулся с проблемой, что `memcpy` переворачивает байты:

```
unsigned char bts[]{0, 1};
unsigned short int i;
memcpy(&i, bts, 2);
```

Здесь i будет равняться не 1, а 256. Почему так и как этого избежать? Не нужно предлагать мне решения с `reinterpret_cast` вместо `memcpy`, поскольку мне нужно интерпретировать массив байт по-разному во время выполнения, а не во время компиляции.

P.S. Только что наткнулся на эндианность, видимо, это то, что нужно. Если это так, то вопрос меняется. Нужно ли беспокоиться о совместимости с разными эндианами и как это сделать?

Comment: `memcpy` ничего не переворачивает — он копирует байты как есть.  Просто при интерпретации двух байтов как значения типа `unsigned short` считается, что байты располагаются от младшего к старшему. См.: [little-endian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83).

Comment: Надёжный способ собрать из двух 8-битных целых одно 16-битное — это использовать битовые операции. Если `CHAR_BIT == 8`, то `unsigned short i = (unsigned(bts[0]) << 8) + bts[1];`. А ещё лучше так: `std::uint8_t bts[] = ...; std::uint16_t i = (std::uint16_t(bts[0]) << 8) + bts[1];`. Вообще в вопросе есть несколько странных утверждений. Почему два байта кодируются 32 битами? Работаете на системе, где в байте больше восьми бит? Что мешает использовать `reinterpret_cast` во время выполнения (ну, кроме возможных проблем из-за нарушения strict aliasing rule и требований по выравниванию)?

Comment: Такая последовательность байт в памяти должна выглядеть как `0000.0000.0000.0001`. Причем на обычной LE машине сначала будет идти младший байт unsigned short.

Comment: `raw_bytes[0]==0` , `raw_bytes[1]==1` ответ 256 правильный. `0*1 + 1 * 256 == 256`

Comment: @wololo 32 бит - это просто опечатка. Спасибо за то, что обратили внимание. А `reinterpret_cast` не могу использовать, поскольку мне нужно по-разному интерпретировать последовательность бит в рантайме. Например человек может выбрать, интерпретировать массив как набор одно или двухбайтовые значения. Если однобайтовые, то выводится 0 и 1 из массива, если двухбайтовые, то только число 01 в данном случае. Как сделать это с `reinerpret_cast` без boilerplate кода я не знаю. Разве есть способ? Ведь в cast'е нужно указывать тип во время компиляции

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По итогам комментариев ответ такой - беспокоиться за разный порядок байт можно и нужно, если происходит обмен данными между разными системами. Решения обычно такие:

**В компьютерных сетях:**

Разработчики договорились, что данные передаются в так называемом *сетевом порядке байт*, после чего, во всех реализациях сокетов Беркли на C для всех платформ появились функции `hton*`, `ntoh*` которые делают необходимую конвертацию (или не делают, если порядок байт на хосте совпадает с сетевым порядком).

**Для этого даже придумали стандарт** и называется он [XDR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation)

Еще одним способом безопасно гонять данные между системами, является перегон их в какой-то текстовый формат, например `JSON` или `XML`. Разумеется, выходной файл от этого раздуется и будет грузится не так быстро, как бинарник, но зато решение лепится на коленке очень быстро и гарантированно работает.

Если вы создаете какой-то свой бинарный формат, можете выбирать один из перечисленных выше вариантов - писать XDR, конвертировать в тексты, или просто договориться, что в версиях для других платформ придется делать конвертацию.